# Given a matrix $A$ such that $A^{\ell}$ is a constant matrix, must $A$ be a constant matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-combinatorics

This problem originates from an exercise in Richard Stanley's *Algebraic Combinatorics*.  The exercise in the text (Chapter 3, Exercise 2(a)) asks

> Let $G$ be a finite graph (allowing loops and multiple edges).  Suppose that there is some $\ell> 0$ such that the number of walks of length $\ell$ from any fixed vertex $u$ to any fixed vertex $v$ is independent of $u$ and $v$.  Show that $G$ has the same number $k$ of edges between any two vertices (including $k$ loops at each vertex.

The hypothesis of the problem (that the number of walks of length $\ell$ between any two vertices is the same) tells us that the adjacency matrix $A(G)$ of $G$ raised to the $\ell$ power is a constant matrix
$$ (A(G))^{\ell} = \begin{pmatrix} c & c & \cdots & c \\ c & c & \cdots & c \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ c & c & \cdots & c \end{pmatrix} $$
for some constant $C$.  We would like to conclude that this means the adjacency matrix itself is a constant matrix (hence, the number of walks of length 1 between any two vertices is the same, i.e., the number of edges between any two vertices is the same).  **Update in response to comments below:** In this case we also have that $A(G)$ is a symmetric matrix which would eliminate some trivial counter examples.

Does this result follow from something in linear algebra?  What is the proof?  If not, is there some other approach that might be more fruitful?

Comment: What does "constant matrix" even mean?

Comment: @5xum A matrix with entries that are all the same.

Comment: Is the zero matrix considered a constant? if so then any nilpotent matrix will do as a counter-example

Comment: @DanielAkech We know that any adjacency matrix is symmetric and nonzero.  I don't think such a matrix can be nilpotent?  I could be wrong.

Comment: @5xum Also, you might want to phrase your question less aggressively.  Saying "what does [blank] _even_ mean?" is somehow accusatory and suggests the terminology is highly nonstandard or the OP is otherwise making some sort of error.  The above the results info on google for "constant matrix" defines it precisely as it is used here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $A(G)$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable.  In particular, this implies that $\ker(A(G)^\ell)=\ker(A(G))$ for all $\ell>0$.  If $A(G)^\ell$ is a constant matrix, then for any $i$ and $j$, $e_i-e_j$ is in its kernel (where $\{e_i\}$ is the standard basis).  Thus $e_i-e_j\in \ker(A(G))$ for every $i$ and $j$, which says that the columns of $A(G)$ are all the same.  Since $A(G)$ is symmetric, this actually implies all the entries of $A(G)$ are the same.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm glad this is true, otherwise I was going to have to try some combinatorics argument.

Answer (score 0):

If $A^k$ is constant (all entries are the same), then we cannot conclude that $A$ is constant as well. For example,

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

is such that $A^2=0$ (so it is constant), but $A$ is not constant.

Comment: Yes, but $A(G)$ is a special kind of matrix (in particular, it is symmetric).

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, I'll add that in.  Thanks.